# PHP rename function does not working

Tags: php, rename

I want to move a file from `one directory` to `another directory` using PHP `rename()` function. But the function is not working. every time it display `Not done`. Your suggestions please.

> Here is my code

```
<?php
    error_reporting(1);
    error_reporting('On');

    include 'includes/config.php';    // database configuration file

    $site_path = "http://www.website.com/";

    $file_name = "images800466507.jpg";
    $currentPath = 'TempImages/'.$file_name;    // ( file permission : 777 )
    $newPath = 'ImagesNew/'.$file_name;      // ( file permission : 755 )

    if( rename($site_path.$currentPath , $site_path.$newPath ) )
        echo 'done';
    else
        echo 'not done';
?>
```

Comment: You should use local path.

Comment: local path means..??? Are you talking about absolute path ..?? '/var/www/website.com/public_html/'

Comment: local path means your project folder path. not online site name

Comment: not ```http://www.website.com``` but something more like ```/var/www/temp_images/``` or wherever your local path is

Comment: '/var/www/website.com/public_html/' ......????

Comment: okay let me try

Comment: sry, but it also not working

Comment: you can remove `$site_path` and try it

Comment: tried....not working :-(

Comment: `$currentPath = '/TempImages/'.$file_name;   
$newPath = '/ImagesNew/'.$file_name;  

if(rename($currentPath , $newPath ))
        echo 'done';
else
        echo 'not done';`

Answer (score 4):

You need to get your real path, for me real path `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/phptest` but you can define `ABSPATH` like `define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__).'/');`

Complete code:

```
 error_reporting(1);
 error_reporting('On');

define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__).'/');

include 'includes/config.php';    // database configuration file

$file_name = "images800466507.jpg";
$currentPath = ABSPATH.'/TempImages/'.$file_name;    // ( file permission : 777 )
$newPath = ABSPATH.'/ImagesNew/'.$file_name;     // ( file permission : 755 )
if( rename($currentPath ,$newPath ) )
   echo 'done';
else
   echo 'not done';
```

I tested and it worked for me.

Comment: I updated the code, it should work on live site without any problem

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps using the full local path might do the trick

```
$filename = 'images800466507.jpg';

$currentpath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'TempImages' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $filename;
$targetpath  = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'ImagesNew' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $filename;

echo realpath( $currentpath ) && rename($currentpath,$targetpath) ? 'done' : 'not done';
```

Does the source file exist at the location specified?

```
if( !file_exists( $currentpath ) ) echo 'Bad Foo - ' . $currentpath . ' not found!';
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `/` before `TempImages/` and `ImagesNew/` directory like `/TempImages/` and `/ImagesNew/`

```
<?php
    error_reporting(1);
    error_reporting('On');

    include 'includes/config.php';    // database configuration file

    //$site_path = "http://www.website.com/";

    $file_name = "images800466507.jpg";
    $currentPath = '/TempImages/'.$file_name;    // ( file permission : 777 )
    $newPath = '/ImagesNew/'.$file_name;      // ( file permission : 755 )

    if( rename($currentPath , $newPath ) )
        echo 'done';
    else
        echo 'not done';
?>
```

more details `rename` function http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php

Comment: @ShanBiswas Did you try `dirname(__FILE__)`like  `$currentPath = ABSPATH.'/TempImages/'.$file_name;`

Comment: All 3 answers is correct under your question. i thinks your problem is another place.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the real path can help:

```
$file = realpath($filename);
```

but it sounds like it could be a permissions issue or an SELinux issue also. You will need apache to be the group on the files in question, and the files should be writeable by the group.

Also, if you have SELinux enabled, you will need to use

```
semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t "/path/to/images/folder(/.*)?"
```

and

```
restorecon -R -v /path/to/images/folder
```